# In poetry, how to specify dependency on different package versions based on hardware

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-poetry

Is there a way how to specify different python package versions for different hardware configurations with Poetry?

E.g. I have several hardware configurations (machine with cuda 10.1 support and cuda 10.0 support). How should I specify dependency on packages that differ in their versions based on these (and also different package names based on the configurations).

Example which configuration is required for different cases:

- CUDA 10.1

  - mxnet-cu101 = 1.6.0
  - torch = 1.5.0
- CUDA 10.0

  - mxnet-cu100 = 1.5.1
  - torch = 1.2.0

Comment: Have you tried environment markers? It seems a good aproach, however it lack of environment variables... (https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers)